# Can Dell optiplex 9010 i7 connect to four monitors using two display port cables, one VGA and USB 3.0 to VGA?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, dell-optiplex

I am a trader, I have four monitors. I am trying to connect them to a *Dell Optiplex 9010* with two display ports, a VGA and two USB 3 ports.

I have two display cables, USB 3.0 to VGA cables. And I have two VGA.
Can it be connected?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the best way you can configure your setup is like this:

- Two displays connected via DisplayPort
- Two displays connected via the USB-3.0 to DVI/HDMI adapters

The VGA output is outdated and probably not able to drive your monitor in an acceptable way. The output of [VGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_Graphics_Array) is limited and not suitable anymore for current setups. Try to avoid it if possible.